# nested ifelse statement with programmatic number of nested levels

Tags: r

I have a matrix of 3 columns. For each row, a non-missing value shall be selected, - if no value is found in column 1, column 2 will be searched, then column 3, and the order will be given by the user.

I am moderately happy with my convoluted nested `ifelse` approach - Alas, this depends on the same length of given columns. But the number of columns should be flexible (thus flexible number of nested ifelse statements) - Meaning, if the user does only select one or two columns, NA shall result even if the undesired column contains a value.

```r
foo_mat <- structure(c(
  NA, 30L, 15, 0, NA, 100L, 87L, NA, 0, NA, 2L, NA,
  10, 0, NA
), .Dim = c(5L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c(
  "a", "b", "c"
)))

foo <- function(x, preced) {
    ifelse(!is.na(x[, preced[1]]), x[, preced[1]],
      ifelse(!is.na(x[, preced[2]]), x[, preced[2]],
        x[, preced[3]]
      )
    )
}

foo_mat
#>       a   b  c
#> [1,] NA 100  2
#> [2,] 30  87 NA
#> [3,] 15  NA 10
#> [4,]  0   0  0
#> [5,] NA  NA NA

foo(foo_mat, c("a", "c", "b"))
#> [1]  2 30 15  0 NA

foo(foo_mat, preced = c("b", "a"))
#> Error in x[, preced[3]]: subscript out of bounds #(of course)

# desired output
#> [1]  100 87 15 0 NA
```

Comment: Your sample data is a good start, but is missing the last portion. I think it needs `"b", "c")))` added, is that right?

Comment: my bad, thanks for seeing it ... but my mouse-drag-copy/paste didn't grab it, so it might be useful to edit it together anyway. Thanks, sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Base R:

```r
apply(foo_mat[,c("a","c","b")], 1, function(z) c(na.omit(z), NA)[1])
# [1]  2 30 15  0 NA
```

The anon-function is a two-step process:

- first, remove any `NA`s, so that we can grab the first non-`NA` value
- second, it is feasible that `na.omit(.)` will return `integer(0)`, which is not what you want, so the `c(., NA)[1]` ensures that after `na.omit(.)`, we always have at least one value in the `c(.)` vector, and we want the first of them; if `na.omit` returns nothing, then at least we have the one `NA`.

Doing this row-wise is done with `apply(foo_mat, 1, ...)`. You control the preference order by re-arranging the columns going into the `apply` data, as in my use of `foo_mat[,c("a","c","b")]`.

As a function:

```r
foo <- function(data, preced = names(data)) apply(data[,preced,drop=FALSE], 1, function(z) c(na.omit(z), NA)[1])
foo(foo_mat, c("a", "c", "b"))
# [1]  2 30 15  0 NA
```

(The `drop=FALSE` is defensive. Base R defaults the behavior of `foo_mat[,"a"]` is a vector instead of a 1-column matrix. This breaks many things, including `apply`. So adding `drop=FALSE` prevents the default reduction behavior.)

An alternative that is about as fast as the other answers:

```r
foo <- function(data, preced) apply(data[,preced,drop=FALSE], 1, function(z) z[!is.na(z)][1])
```

Same functionality, fewer calls, simple logic.

(Attribution: this alternative is a combination of work from @tmfmnk, @Tjebo, and me. Thanks!)

Comment: FYI, the answer provided by @RuiBarradas provides the same results. But on data this size, that function is over twice as fast.

Comment: I think `c(z[!is.na(z)], NA)[1]` can even be written `z[!is.na(z)][1]`, because `integer(0)[1]` is `NA`

Answer (score 4):

Here is a function `foo` that works as required with the posted examples.

```
foo <- function(x, preced){
  apply(x[, preced], 1, function(y){
    w <- !is.na(y)
    if(any(w)) y[w][1] else NA
  })
}

foo(foo_mat, c("a", "c", "b"))
#[1]  2 30 15  0 NA
foo(foo_mat, preced = c("b", "a"))
#[1] 100  87  15   0  NA
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of the nested `ifelse`, it may be better to create a function with `coalesce`

```
foo <- function(data, preced) {
        do.call(dplyr::coalesce, as.data.frame(data[, preced]))
       }


foo(foo_mat, c("a", "c", "b"))
#[1]  2 30 15  0 NA
foo(foo_mat, c("b", "a"))
#[1] 100  87  15   0  NA
```

---

`coalesce` automatically picks up the first non-NA for each row based on the columns in the selected dataset

---

Or we can use a vectorized option in `base R` with `max.col`

```
foo1 <- function(data, preced) {
         tmp <- data[, preced]
         i1 <- seq_len(nrow(tmp))
         j1 <- max.col(!is.na(tmp), "first")
         out <- tmp[cbind(i1, j1)]
         out
    }

foo1(foo_mat, c("a", "c", "b"))
#[1]  2 30 15  0 NA
foo1(foo_mat, c("b", "a"))
#[1] 100  87  15   0  NA
```